# Type 'MyWeights' does not conform to protocol 'NSCopying'

Tags: ios, swift, nsobject, swift-protocols, metal-performance-shaders

I am using Metal Performance Shader to set up a neural network, and encountered the issue when writing the weights initialization class: Type 'MyWeights' does not conform to protocol 'NSCopying'. What caused the error, and how to fix this?

PS. I tried to fix it by adding the copy() function, however I do not know what to return or what it means.

```
import Foundation
import MetalPerformanceShaders

class MyWeights: NSObject, MPSCNNConvolutionDataSource {
//Error: Type 'MyWeights' does not conform to protocol 'NSCopying'

/*
func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
    return self
}
*/

let name: String
let kernelWidth: Int
let kernelHeight: Int
let inputFeatureChannels: Int
let outputFeatureChannels: Int

var data: Data?

init(name: String, kernelWidth: Int, kernelHeight: Int,
     inputFeatureChannels: Int, outputFeatureChannels: Int,
     useLeaky: Bool = true) {
    self.name = name
    self.kernelWidth = kernelWidth
    self.kernelHeight = kernelHeight
    self.inputFeatureChannels = inputFeatureChannels
    self.outputFeatureChannels = outputFeatureChannels
}

func dataType() -> MPSDataType {
    return .float32
}

func descriptor() -> MPSCNNConvolutionDescriptor {
    let desc = MPSCNNConvolutionDescriptor(kernelWidth: kernelWidth,
                                           kernelHeight: kernelHeight,
                                           inputFeatureChannels: inputFeatureChannels,
                                           outputFeatureChannels: outputFeatureChannels)
    return desc
}

func weights() -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer {
    return UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: (data! as NSData).bytes)
}

func biasTerms() -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>? {
    return nil
}

func load() -> Bool {
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "dat") {
        do {
            data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            return true
        } catch {
            print("Error: could not load \(url): \(error)")
        }
    }
    return false
}

func purge() {
    data = nil
}

func label() -> String? {
    return name
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's telling you **exactly** what to do.

You need to declare that your class conforms to the `NSCopying` protocol, and then you need to implement the only function in that protocol, `copy(with:)`

```
class MyWeights: NSObject, MPSCNNConvolutionDataSource, NSCopying {

    func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        return MyWeights(
          name: self.name,
          kernelWidth: self.kernelWidth,
          kernelHeight: self.kernelHeight,
          inputFeatureChannels: self.inputFeatureChannels,
          outputFeatureChannels: self.outputFeatureChannels,
          useLeaky: self.useLeaky)
    }
    //The rest of your class
}
```

Comment: In objective C, you'd be missing -(nonnull instancetype) copyWithZone: (NSZone * __nullable) zone

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the entire NSCopying protocol

```
class MyWeights: NSObject, MPSCNNConvolutionDataSource, NSCopying {

    init(/* ... */) {
    // your init...

        super.init() // NSObject init
    }

    // add this method
    func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        return super.copy() // NSObject copy
    }
    //The rest of your class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The convolution data source protocol has changed over the years and recently added the NSCopying protocol so that the MPSCNNConvolution can itself conform to NSCopying. It is possible that some sample code didn’t move forward. MPS should be checking available selectors so that this isn’t a binary compatibility issue, but moving forward, your protocol adopters should conform to NSCopying so that the framework can behave as advertised. The answers above demonstrate how.